# Lentidão na busca por índice do Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa-2.0

Isso é um *[**crosspost**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619648/why-hibernate-search-is-slow-even-with-few-records)* que fiz no *stackoverflow* em inglês. Está difícil entender (e corrigir) esse problema. Vou colocar aqui para ver se alguém em nossa comunidade já passou por isso e sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo.

O que ocorre é que eu tenho uma view no **Oracle**. Essa *view* demora um pouco para ser executada (~7 segundos), apesar de retornar poucos registros. Retornam **cerca de 5756 linhas** quando eu faço uma consulta simples como `select * from my_view;`

Até aí não tenho nenhum problema. O problema ocorre no meu projeto onde eu tenho uma entidade do [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) mapeada para essa view e também um mapeamento de índice do [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/) para que eu possa fazer uma busca fulltext em todo o índice.

Melhor mostrar o código. Essa é minha entidade mapeada:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 244555315052436669L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String user;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "phone", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String phone;

    //Getters and Setters ommited
}
```

Percebam que há mapeamento normal do Hibernate / JPA e do Hibernate Search (`@Field`, por exemplo). Até aqui legal. Acho que está tudo certo. Então criei um método para criar o índice. O método é esse:

```
public void index() throws DAOException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(Person.class)
            .purgeAllOnStart(Boolean.TRUE)
            .optimizeOnFinish(Boolean.TRUE)
            .startAndWait();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("Error creating index", e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

Aqui também, tudo certo. Ele cria o índice no sistema de arquivos certinho. Agora que vem o problema. A busca em si em cima do índice criado. Essa busca, por ser uma busca fulltext, deveria ser extremamente rápida, afinal o Hibernate Search é construído em cima do Lucene, que preza por performance.

Quando eu faço uma busca por termos, até que vai bem (não tão bem, mas vai), **o problema ocorre quando eu busca sem nenhum termo, ou seja, quando eu quero que me retorne todos os registros do índice.** Demora mais de 40 segundos uma busca sem termos! Um absurdo de tempo para uma busca indexada.

O código da minha busca sem termos:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(qb.all().createQuery());
Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name", SortField.STRING));
fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

Eu venho batendo cabeça já há algum tempo sem sucesso. Qualquer sugestão ou dica é bem vinda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

O que acontece é que o Hibernate Search, ao recuperar os dados no índice, **usa esses dados para fazer uma busca na *view* no banco de dados** e recuperar os dados completos da entidade mapeada. Ao buscar os dados na *view*, o tempo de execução da query era demorado e isso fazia com que minha aplicação ficasse lenta.

Para resolver o problema eu tive que usar a funcionalidade de **[Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-query.html)** do Hibernate Search. Essa funcionalidade permite que eu guarde as informações da entidade no índice, deixando o índice maior, porém muito mais rápido.

Indo diretamente ao ponto, o que eu tive que fazer foi alterar minha entidade para ela guardar os dados no índice utilizando a anotação `store = Store.YES`. Minha entidade ficou assim:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 244555315052436669L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String user;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "phone", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String phone;

    //Getters and Setters ommited
}
```

Depois, eu tive que mudar a forma como eu fazia a query em cima do índice. Essa mudança é para especificar que quero usar *projections*. Então meu método de busca no índice ficou da seguinte forma:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(qb.all().createQuery());

// Adicionei essa linha para usar projections
fullTextQuery.setProjection("id", "name", "email", "user", "phone");

Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name", SortField.STRING));
fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

Agora o problema de usar Projections é que o Hibernate Search **retorna uma lista de array de objetos** e não a lista com a minha entidade. Em outras palavras, o Hibernate Search, com Projections, retorna um `List<Object[]>` e sem o Projections retorna `List<Person>`. Então, tive que criar um método auxiliar para converter o `List<Object[]>` para `List<Person>`. O código:

```
private List<Person> toList(List<Object[]> objPeople) {
    List<Person> lstPeople = new LinkedList<Person>();
    Person Person = null;

    for(Object[] objPerson : objPeople) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(Long.parseLong(objPerson[0].toString()));
        p.setName(String.valueOf(objPerson[1] == null ? "" : objPerson[1]));
        p.setEmail(String.valueOf(objPerson[2] == null ? "" : objPerson[2]));
        p.setUser(String.valueOf(objPerson[3] == null ? "" : objPerson[3]));
        p.setPhone(String.valueOf(objPerson[4] == null ? "" : objPerson[4]));
        lstPeople.add(p);
    }

    return lstPeople;
}
```

**E pronto**! Agora funciona e muito, mas muito rápido. **A busca em cima do indice sem palavra chave alguma demora milisegundos.**